# WordPress dummy data for theme design

Tags: theme-development

I know there are a lot of options (exported files, plugins) but I am looking for a specific one that I used to use but now I have misplaced a local copy of it and can't seem to find it on Google.

It was related to Gorilla themes, I guess. It has meaningful content and not just `lorem ipsum`.

If anybody can point me to it, then that would be great.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You’ll find the latest test data on [svn.automattic.com](http://svn.automattic.com/wpcom-themes/demo/) as a XML file. Last time I used this, there were no languages like Arabic or Chinese and no complex tables. You have to add such data on your own, I’m afraid.

Comment: please read the question again, I didn't ask for this. I am looking for something else, a specific file.

Comment: @Ashfame - So you're not talking about the [theme unit test data then](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test)? You can see what this data looks like [here](http://wpthemetestdata.wordpress.com/).

Comment: @Ashfame From your question I cannot see what else you want. May I ask you to clarify your intention?

Answer (score 1):

I think you talking about WPCandy Sample WordPress Content

http://wpcandy.com/made/the-sample-post-collection